# Erro Javascript - DataTables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-datatables, datatable

Olá já tenho um código que funciona no dataTables em uma página, então peguei o modelo e as únicas alterações que fiz foi *mudar o nome do js* , *mudar nome da função $() e .column(coloquei a posição da coluna)* o restante deixei igual no caso a estrutura, só sei o básico de js e vim recorrer atrás de ajuda.

aqui eu chamo no html meu js:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="js-table-lista-cliente-mes" style="min-width: 100%; width: 100%;">
```

segue o código do js e html :

```js
var table = $('#js-table-lista-cliente-mes').DataTable({
  "sDom": '<"search-box"r>ltip',
  "lengthChange": false,
  "language": {
    "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
    "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
    "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
    "sInfoPostFix": "",
    "sInfoThousands": ".",
    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
    "sProcessing": "Processando...",
    "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
    "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
    "oPaginate": {
      "sNext": "Próximo",
      "sPrevious": "Anterior",
      "sFirst": "Primeiro",
      "sLast": "Último"
    },
    "oAria": {
      "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
      "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
    }
  }
});

$('#fini').change(function() {
  table.draw();
});
$('#ffin').change(function() {
  table.draw();
});

$("#searchbox").on("keyup search input paste cut", function() {
  table.search(this.value).draw();
});

$('#codMaster').on('keyup', function() {
  table
    .column(2)
    .search(this.value)
    .draw();
});

$('#razaoSocial').on('keyup', function() {
  table
    .column(3)
    .search(this.value)
    .draw();
});


$('#nomeFantasia').on('keyup', function() {
  table
    .column(4)
    .search(this.value)
    .draw();
});


$('#tipo').on('keyup', function() {
  table
    .column(5)
    .search(this.value)
    .draw();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" layout:decorator="LayoutPadrao">

<head>
</head>
<section layout:fragment="conteudo">
  <div class="conteudo">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="js-table-lista-cliente-mes" style="min-width: 100%; width: 100%;">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="th-1 text-left col-md-1">
                <div class="search btn btn-default">
                  <a href="#" class="search-icon"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                  </a> <input type="text" id='codMaster' style="width: 7em;" />
                </div>
              </th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th class="text-center col-md-2">
                <div class="search btn btn-default">
                  <a href="#" class="search-icon"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                  </a> <input type="text" id='razaoSocial' />
                </div>
              </th>
              <th class="text-center col-md-1">
                <div class="search btn btn-default">
                  <a href="#" class="search-icon"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                  </a> <input type="text" id='nomeFantasia' style="width: 7em;" />
                </div>
              </th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th class="text-center col-md-1 ">
                <div class="search btn btn-default">
                  <a href="#" class="search-icon"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                  </a> <input type="text" id='tipo' style="width: 7em;" />
                </div>
              </th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
            <th:block th:each="historicoClienteMes,idx : ${listaVendasCliente}">
              <th:block th:if="${idx.index == 0}">
                <thead>
                  <tr style="font-size: 12px">
                    <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[0]}"></th>
                    <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[1]}"></th>
                    <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[2]}"></th>
                    <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[3]}"></th>
                    <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[4]}"></th>
                    <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[5]}"></th>
                    <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[6]}"></th>
                    <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[7]}"></th>
                    <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[8]}"></th>
                    <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[9]}"></th>
                    <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[10]}"></th>
                    <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[11]}"></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
              </th:block>
              <th:block th:if="${idx.index > 0}">
                <tbody>
                  <tr style="font-size: 12px">
                    <td class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[0]}"></td>
                    <td class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[1]}"></td>
                    <td class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[2]}"></td>
                    <td class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[3]}"></td>
                    <td class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[4]}"></td>
                    <td class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[5]}"></td>
                    <td class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[6]}"></td>
                    <td class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[7]}"></td>
                    <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[8]}"></th>
                    <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[9]}"></th>
                    <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[10]}"></th>
                    <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[11]}"></th>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </th:block>
            </th:block>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

</html>
```

Comment: O que tu tens como retorno disso? Ele simplesmente não carrega? Aparece algum erro no console? O que mais especificamente não está funcionando?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:90)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:90)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.n [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.min.js:83)
    at w.fn.init.h.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.min.js:165)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (htk.js:174)
    at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)

Comment: Quando me ocorreu, incluí o <tbody></tbody> e funcionou.

Comment: onde você colocou? pois o meu já está com tbody já

Comment: @JoyceSD teu `<tbody></tbody>` esta dentro de um th:block na thead, tenta colocar um tbody filho direto da tua table, entr eo </thead> e o </table>

Comment: atualizei o código na resposta abaixo!

Comment: @evandrobm verifiquei o tbody e mesmo assim não foi pelo erro do console Mdata é algo no html , provável que seja.

Comment: @JoyceSD evita responder com updates da pergunta, tu pode editar a tua pergunta quando precisar, para deixar mais organizado para quem for visualizar depois.

Comment: vlw farei isso ...

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta comentando do erro, para ficar mais fácil de visualizar

Answer (score 1):

O **DataTables** exige uma tabela bem formatada para funcionar, esse erro é comum quando ele não encontra uma tag ou se ela contém erros. Segue um exemplo de tabela:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Coluna 1</th>
            <th>Coluna 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> <!-- ESSE TBODY NÃO TEM NO SEU CÓDIGO -->
        <tr> <!-- Linha 1 -->
            <td>Linha 1 Coluna 1</td>
            <td>Linha 1 Coluna 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Linha 2 -->
            <td>Linha 2 Coluna 1</td>
            <td>Linha 2 Coluna 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

O teu `<tbody>` está dentro do `<thead>`. E o **DataTables** exige que a tag `<table>` tenha pelo menos como filhas as tags `<thead>` e `<tbody>`, e qualquer outra tag fora do esperado também gera erro.

Esse erro também ocorre quando tu tem mais colunas no thead do que no tbody, exemplo:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr> <!-- Cabeçalho com 3 células -->
            <th>Coluna 1</th>
            <th>Coluna 2</th>
            <th>Coluna 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr> <!-- Linha com duas células -->
            <td>Linha 1 Coluna 1</td>
            <td>Linha 1 Coluna 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Tenta limpar a tua `table` e ir criando ela aos poucos, ver se o DataTables vai pegar, e quando ele parar de funcionar, tu vai saber o que tem de diferente se o incremento for pequeno, vai transformando aos poucos uma tabela vazia até chegar nessa tua bem complexa.

Comment: estou fazendo isso agora seguindo sua dica, refazendo a tabela aos poucos, obrigada!

Comment: @JoyceSD qualquer dúvida é só perguntar, se der certo não esquece de aceitar a resposta, é importante para ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida que você no futuro!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var table = $('#js-table-lista-cliente-mes').DataTable({
  "sDom": '<"search-box"r>ltip',
  "lengthChange": false,
  "language": {
   "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
   "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
   "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
   "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
   "sInfoPostFix": "",
   "sInfoThousands": ".",
   "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
   "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
   "sProcessing": "Processando...",
   "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
   "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
   "oPaginate": {
    "sNext": "Próximo",
    "sPrevious": "Anterior",
    "sFirst": "Primeiro",
    "sLast": "Último"
   },
   "oAria": {
    "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
    "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
   }
  }
 });

 $('#fini').change(function() {
  table.draw();
 });
 $('#ffin').change(function() {
  table.draw();
 });

 $("#searchbox").on("keyup search input paste cut", function() {
  table.search(this.value).draw();
 });

 $('#codMaster').on('keyup', function() {
  table
  .column(2)
  .search(this.value)
  .draw();
 });

 $('#razaoSocial').on('keyup', function() {
  table
  .column(3)
  .search(this.value)
  .draw();
 });


 $('#nomeFantasia').on('keyup', function() {
  table
  .column(4)
  .search(this.value)
  .draw();
 });


 $('#tipo').on('keyup', function() {
  table
  .column(5)
  .search(this.value)
  .draw();
 });
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" layout:decorator="LayoutPadrao">
<head>
</head>
<section layout:fragment="conteudo">
<div class="conteudo">
 <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="js-table-lista-cliente-mes" style="min-width: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th class="th-1 text-left col-md-1">
       <div class="search btn btn-default">
        <a href="#" class="search-icon"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </a> <input type="text" id='codMaster' style="width: 7em;" />
       </div>
      </th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th class="text-center col-md-2">
       <div class="search btn btn-default">
        <a href="#" class="search-icon"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </a> <input type="text" id='razaoSocial' />
       </div>
      </th>
      <th class="text-center col-md-1">
       <div class="search btn btn-default">
        <a href="#" class="search-icon"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </a> <input type="text" id='nomeFantasia' style="width: 7em;" />
       </div>
      </th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th class="text-center col-md-1 ">
       <div class="search btn btn-default">
        <a href="#" class="search-icon"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </a> <input type="text" id='tipo' style="width: 7em;" />
       </div>
      </th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <th:block th:each="historicoClienteMes,idx : ${listaVendasCliente}">
      <th:block th:if="${idx.index == 0}">
      <thead>
       <tr style="font-size: 12px">
        <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[0]}"></th>
        <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[1]}"></th>
        <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[2]}"></th>
        <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[3]}"></th>
        <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[4]}"></th>
        <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[5]}"></th>
        <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[6]}"></th>
        <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[7]}"></th>
        <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[8]}"></th>
        <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[9]}"></th>
        <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[10]}"></th>
        <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[11]}"></th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
    </th:block>
    <th:block th:if="${idx.index > 0}">
     <tbody>
      <tr style="font-size: 12px">
       <td class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[0]}"></td>
       <td class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[1]}"></td>
       <td class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[2]}"></td>
       <td class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[3]}"></td>
       <td class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[4]}"></td>
       <td class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[5]}"></td>
       <td class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[6]}"></td>
       <td class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[7]}"></td>
       <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[8]}"></th>
       <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[9]}"></th>
       <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[10]}"></th>
       <th class="text-center col-md-1" th:text="${historicoClienteMes[11]}"></th>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </th:block>
    </th:block>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</section>
</html>
```